# Iframe/embedded YTvideo keeps playing when modal window closed

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've added embedded videos on [my website's 'Video' section](https://twotailsmedia.com/staging/#videos). A weird thing's happening, though. If I play the video, then 'X' out the window while the video's playing, the audio still plays even though the window is closed.

So it seems like "closing" my window doesn't really close the video.  I've added "?enablejsapi=1" to the end of the YouTube URL to enable the YouTube API, but I'm not sure what my next step is.

How do I set up the iframe so the video stops playing when the modal window is closed/X'ed out?
Here's the code for that window + embedded iframe:

```
  <article id="videos">

    <h2 class="videos">Our Work</h2>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/973w2QTswQI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <p>Adipiscing magna ...</p>

    <p>Nullam et orci ...</p>

    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's integrated in modals to stop vidoes when you press X. You have to explicitly include in the function that you want to stop the video using [stopVideo command](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls).

Comment: I've heard that it might be fixable using the YouTube IFrame API that you linked.  But honestly have no idea how to set up the API so that it responds to the modal.  Any thoughts?